# Am I making use of REST if I have implemented an Android app that connects to a localhost?

Tags: rest, android

Would I be using REST or would my app be considered RESTful if I was using the Google Volley library to connect to a database on localhost?

Answer (score 4):

No.

1. REST has to do with working with resources over the Internet; LocalHost doesn't really qualify as such, unless perhaps you're running a web server on LocalHost.
2. Google Volley is a client-side library.  It can potentially connect to RESTful resources, but it, in and of itself, does not make something RESTful.

If you simulated a RESTful resource on LocalHost, and then connected to that with Google Volley using RESTful protocols, then yes, you could probably call that RESTful.

**Further Reading**
[How I Explained REST to My Wife](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-i-explained-rest-my-wife-jason-roell)